# Syntax error "data block name must be followed by << EODmarker"

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot. I just want to plot a graph I found on wikipedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Double_exponential_moving_average_weightings_N%3D10.png

But I get this syntax error "data block name must be followed by << EODmarker"

Thanks

```
$N = 10;
$f = 1 - 2/($N+1);


$total = 0;
foreach $i (0..39) {
  $value =
    2 * 100.0 * (1 - $f) * ($f ** $i)
      - 100.0 * (1 - $f) * (1 - $f) * ($i + 1) * ($f ** $i);
  print "$i $value\n";
  $total += $value;
}
print "# total $total (should approach 100)\n";
```

Comment: That code is Perl, like mentioned in the link you post: "and dema.data created by this bit of perl"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same result could be achieved using `gnuplot` only.

```
N = 10
f = 1.0 - 2.0/(N + 1)

total = 0

set print 'dema.data'
    do for [i=0:39:1]{
        value = \
            2 * 100 * (1.0 - f) * (f**i) \
              - 100 * (1.0 - f) * (1.0 - f) * (i + 1.0) * (f**i)
        print sprintf('%02d    % .5f', i, value)
        total = total + value
    }
unset print
print sprintf('# total %g (should approach 100)', total)
```

To view the result, I'm use a modified `gnuplot`code from your link.

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800, 600
set output 'output.png'

set xrange [-0.5:39.5]
set xtics axis 5
set mxtics 5

set yrange [-4:35]
set format y "%.1f"

unset key
set style fill solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.6 relative
plot "dema.data" with boxes
```

Which produces [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCfn3.png).

Comment: Thanks so much GRSousaJr, graph extracted fine. As I have to compare different sets of inputs for my research, can you extract the mathematical function used for the dema.data calculations?

Comment: This a very specific question. Maybe I can't help you. But you can check the links: [link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_moving_average), [link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) and [link3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Double_exponential_smoothing).